# How to pass more than one parameter to an actionFunction?

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="if(confirm('Are you sure?'))
    {remove2('{!oplist.lineNumber1}');}">

<img src="{!$Resource.Red_Cross}" alt="Remove" title="Remove" /></a>



<apex:actionFunction name="remove2" action="{!removeoppline2}" reRender="thePB">
    <apex:param name="name" value="rono" assignTo="{!proname}" />
</apex:actionFunction>
```

I also want to send record id like {!oplist.opplineNo.id} on remove image click..how can i send both line number and recordid simontaneously....pl help me with it

UPDATED

```
for(OpportunityLineItem l:lOpp) {    
    wrapperopllist.add(new linenumberclass(l,m));
    m++;
}

  <apex:repeat value="{!wrapperopllist}" var="oplist" rows="{!PageSize}" id="wrapid">

    <tr height="50px">
        <td class="Tdtext">{!oplist.lineNumber}
            <div id="{!rno}" style="display:none">
                <apex:image value="{!$Resource.Warning_Image}" height="15px" id="im" />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="Tdtext">{!oplist.oppLineNo.PricebookEntry.Product2.name}

        </td>



        <td class="Tdtext">
            <apex:inputField value="{!oplist.oppLineNo.Exclusive__c}" />
        </td>
        <td class="Tdtext">
            <apex:inputField value="{!oplist.oppLineNo.TV_Everywhere__c}" />
        </td>
        <td class="Tdtext">
            <apex:inputField value="{!oplist.oppLineNo.Description}" />
        </td>
        <td class="Tdtext">

            <a href="javascript:;" onclick="if(confirm('Are you sure?')){remove1('{!oplist.oppLineNo.id}','{!oplist.lineNumber}');}">
                                   <img src="{!$Resource.Red_Cross}" alt="Remove" title="Remove" />
                             </a>
            <apex:variable value="{!rno+1}" var="rno" />
        </td>

    </tr>

</apex:repeat>

<apex:actionFunction name="remove1" action="{!removeoppline}" reRender="thePB">
    <apex:param name="id" value="rno" assignTo="{!deleteid}" />

    <apex:param name="name" value="rno" assignTo="{!proname}" />
<apex:actionFunction/>


remove method

public void removeoppline() {
    system.debug('==='+wrapperopllist);
    System.debug('"""""""""""'+deleteid);
    wrapperopllist.remove(proname-1);

    for(Integer i = proname-1; i < wrapperopllist.size(); i++) {
        wrapperopllist[i].linenumber=proname;
        proname++;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**StackExchange Tip:** You should update your question (and ensure future ones) to something more generic like *'How to pass more than one parameter to a actionFunction?*'. And try to provide as much background as you can about the information being displayed/manipulated.

**Answer:** Assuming you can obtain the Id via the 'oplist' binding, and given what you've shared about this on a previous quesiton, this should work just fine...

```
remove2('{!oplist.lineNumber1}', '{!opList.oppLineNo.Id}');
```

Then add a second apex:param like so...

```
<apex:actionFunction name="remove2" action="{!removeoppline2}" reRender="thePB">
  <apex:param name="name" value="rono" assignTo="{!proname}"/>
  <apex:param name="id" value="rono" assignTo="{!proid}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>
```

**NOTE:** Make sure to expose 'proid' as a new controller variable, much like you have 'proname'.

The important thing with actionFunction parameters is to pass them in the correct order, although they are named, the name does not really get used. As you can see above, it's the order they are passed.

Comment: hey thanks...great..i wanted exactly like this..thanks again...

Comment: but i have doubt as oppLineNo is intance of opportunitylineitem...i should get {!opList.oppLineNo.Id} opportunity lineitemid intead i am getting opportunityid..i dont now why that is happening...

Comment: No problem, I've marked up your question for you as well, reads much better and will help future people benefit from your question and my answer.

Comment: can you figure where i can be wrong as i am getting opportunityid instead of oportunitylineitemid in proid..?

Comment: Can you update your answer with a little more VF markup, I think i know what your doing wrong, but need to see what VF markup your using to output the table.

Comment: i have updated with vf makup...

Comment: Nope still cannot spot it, maybe if you post removeoppline code as well? Are you sure you using 'deleteid' (you mentioned 'proid' in your previous comment). BTW, do try to format your code samples better, remove white space and try to avoid long lines if you can.

Comment: yes..i am using deleteid.i will be careful in future...

Comment: i have added remove method...

Comment: i also wanted to tell you when i pass only id to param..i get an exception id(opportunitylineitemid) string cant be coverted to number...but thats an opportunitylineitemid that shows..i dont know why..? remove2( '{!opList.oppLineNo.Id}');

Comment: I think your going to need some more debug on this, how about if(confirm('Are you sure? {!oplist.oppLineNo.id}')) to check the Id being passed to the action function. Or just outputing a <td> with {!oplist.oppLineNo.id} in it.

Comment: i tried as you said...when i just output using {!oplist.oppLineNo.id} it shows opportunitylineitemid

Comment: also i tried with the other..passing only id to the controller ..and its showing opportunityid not opportunitylineitemid...but shows opportunitylineitemid when i output it to the screen..something is still wrong...

Comment: Yeah most strange, can you post the full code of your VF page and controller, to https://gist.github.com/?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/79e4aa28a69943400f6c i have posted my code...i have removed some extra code..otherwise it would have been too large...

Comment: can you pl have a look ..??

Comment: i am not able to figure out the problem...

Comment: hey..did u notice any problem...?